# MDIForms: WriteXml : Null reference exception

Tags: c#, mdi

I've been trying to read xml and print it in datagrid and then again on clicking save write it back to the same file so that if i open it after sometime, i can have the new files. So, this is what I did:

```
  DataSet ds;
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cmd = new SqlCommand("getCustomers", conn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    ds = new DataSet();
    //da.Fill(ds, "Productslist");
    ds.ReadXml(@"C:\Users\Nishanth\documents\visual studio   
        2010\Projects\Ex1\Ex2\ShoppingCart1.ds");
    dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
}
```

So,here i read from xml and assign it a grid. In the next few lines i write an event when I click save button on the parent mdi form and call the child form's writeX method.

```
public void writeX()
{
    MessageBox.Show("I'm in writeX()");

    ds.WriteXml(@"C:\Users\Nishanth\documents\visual studio           
        2010\Projects\Ex1\Ex2\ShoppingCart1.ds");
}
```

here, at WriteXml step, I get and error saying

```
   Null Reference Exception : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Parent form code

```
    private void customer_clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 f2 = new Form2();
        f2.MdiParent = this;

        f2.MaximizeBox = true;

        f2.Show();
    }

    private void products_clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Form1 f = new Form1();
        f.MdiParent = this;

        f.MaximizeBox = true;

        f.Show();



    }

    private void saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 f2 = new Form2();
        f2.writeX();
    }
```

So, can u please let me know the mistake i've been doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time you're calling `writeX`, `ds` has not been instantiated.  With the code provided, it's impossible to tell why that's the case.

It's most likely you have two `ds`'s declared in different scopes.

**EDIT**:  Given the updated example shows that it's not an issue of `ds`'s scope, the next thing to look for is the lifetime of the `Form2` object.  It's a likely two different instances are in use when NullReferenceException occurs.  That is, a second instance was likely created but never shown, the Load event never firing, and `ds` never getting instantiated.

**EDIT**:  It's obvious now.  You're not using the same `Form2` in `saveToolStripMenuItem_Click` as you are in `customer_clicked`.

You'll need a class-level `Form2` instance.

```
Form2 _form2;
private void customer_clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _form2 = new Form2();
    _form2.MdiParent = this;

    _form2.MaximizeBox = true;

    _form2.Show();
}

private void saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // a NullReference is still possible if this is called before customer_clicked
    _form2.writeX();
}
```

Comment: can u let me know the way to handle this?

Comment: I instantiated dataset globally. then updated ds in form2_load and then then i write xml which writes nothing(clears everything ; guess ds is null).

Comment: In other words, the code you've posted likely doesn't matter -- the scope of the `Form2` instance in the parent form does.

Comment: `ds` is not global in your example; it's class-level.

Comment: yeah .. sorry .. thats true its class-level